# Instance abstract class that is implemented elsewhere?

Tags: c++, class, instance

I'm making a plugin DLL for 3dsmax. The SDK includes one particular class full of pure virtual functions that the documentation says are implemented by max itself. I know these functions are implemented, because class instances are sometimes passed to my plugin through functions in my plugin that max calls from its core api.

However, if I try to instance that class within my code, I cannot since all of its functions are pure virtual in the 3dsmax SDK.

Is there any way to tell the c++ compiler that even though the functions it sees are pure virtual, they are implemented somewhere else (in another .dll visible to the program)? The declarations of the functions in question are not in any of the 3dsmax .libs or includes...so it's 100% certain that they're outside the scope of my code....but they *are* out there.

I'm new to c++ so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure virtual means they aren't implemented for that class. That class is indeed impossible to instantiate, either for your code or the 3dsmax code.

What is the case is that 3dsmax has *subclasses* which do provide the implementation for those virtual methods. They then provide you access to those instances of the subclasses via pointers to the abstract base class. But you aren't getting pointers to an instance of the base class itself.

If the 3dsmax API provides any concrete base classes which you can instantiate, then you should instantiate those. If not, then you will have to use the API as intended to get pointers to the instances that you want. This is a good thing. You should follow the API.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize that max was actually subclassing the class I want. Guess that means I'm out of luck!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't instantiate a subclass of an abstract class for which you have no class definition available (i.e. a header file).